# Is there an iPad app with a Pen tool similar to Procreate?

Tags: software-recommendation, pen-tool, ipad

I am having trouble finding an app for iPad with a pen (Bézier curve) tool, that is **not** primarily a vector drawing app.

I have been using Procreate for iPad for awhile now, and I enjoy the simplicity and ease of the app. It feels very natural after having used Photoshop for a couple of years. However, I miss the pen tool as I often used it for line art when working in PS.

Is there any digital painting app with a built in pen tool?

Comment: Have you tried [these](https://cellularnews.com/mobile-apps/best-procreate-alternatives/) alternatives for Procreate?

Answer (score 0):

[Affinity photo](https://affinity.serif.com/en-gb/photo/ipad/) is as close as you can get to Photoshop on the ipad, pen tool included. It is very powerful, and unlike procreate, quite complicated, but you should be able to do digital painting with vectors combined.

Edit 2021: there is now Affinity Designer on the iPad, which is closer to Procreate I think. It's still much more complex that Procreate, but combines raster tools with complex brushes & vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Late to this question but for anyone coming to it later: do not go with Affinity, as it is closer to a photo editor than a drawing/painting app like Procreate.

What you want is Infinite Painter. It has pen/bezier curve tools like Photoshop, along with actual shape tools and true any-angle, any points polylines.

Procreate5 lacks these basic tools. Infinite Painter is just a better, but much less well known app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Autodesk's Sketchbook Pro](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/autodesk-sketchbook/id883738213)

Answer (score -1):

I strongly agree with Spiral's answer, as I myself use Affinity Photo on iPad - I would also advocate you look at Concepts - it IS a vector drawing app, but has some excellent brushes and systems for overall sketching and design.